# File naming problem with Python

Tags: python, mkdir

I am trying to iterate through a number .rtf files and for each file: read the file, perform some operations, and then write new files into a sub-directory as plain text files with the same name as the original file, but with .txt extensions. The problem I am having is with the file naming.

If a file is named foo.rtf, I want the new file in the subdirectory to be foo.txt. here is my code:

```
import glob
import os
import numpy as np


dir_path = '/Users/me/Desktop/test/'
file_suffix = '*.rtf'
output_dir = os.mkdir('sub_dir')
for item in glob.iglob(dir_path + file_suffix):
    with open(item, "r") as infile:
        reader = infile.readlines()
        matrix = []
        for row in reader:
            row = str(row)
            row = row.split()
            row = [int(value) for value in row]
            matrix.append(row)
        np_matrix = np.array(matrix)
        inv_matrix = np.transpose(np_matrix)
        new_file_name = item.replace('*.rtf', '*.txt') # i think this line is the problem?
        os.chdir(output_dir)
        with open(new_file_name, mode="w") as outfile:
            outfile.write(inv_matrix)
```

When I run this code, I get a Type Error:

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

How can I fix my code to write new files into a subdirectory and change the file extensions from .rtf to .txt? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can we get a stacktrace?

Comment: Seems unlikely the marked line would raise that error.

Comment: Would you mind marking an answer as accepted or does no answer tell you what you need ?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the help. I've now marked an accepted answer, sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `item.replace`, check out some of the functions in the `os.path` module (http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html).  They're made for splitting up and recombining parts of filenames.  For instance, `os.path.splitext` will split a filename into a file path and a file extension.

Let's say you have a file `/tmp/foo.rtf` and you want to move it to `/tmp/foo.txt`:

```
old_file = '/tmp/foo.rtf'
(file,ext) = os.path.splitext(old_file)
print 'File=%s Extension=%s' % (file,ext)
new_file = '%s%s' % (file,'.txt')
print 'New file = %s' % (new_file)
```

Or if you want the one line version:

```
old_file = '/tmp/foo.rtf'
new_file = '%s%s' % (os.path.splitext(old_file)[0],'.txt')
```

Answer (score 2):

I've never used glob, but here's an alternative way without using a module:
You can easily strip the suffix using

```
name = name[:name.rfind('.')]
```

and then add the new suffix:

```
name = name + '.txt'
```

Why not using a function ?

```
def change_suffix(string, new_suffix):
    i = string.rfind('.')
    if i < 0:
        raise ValueError, 'string does not have a suffix'
    if not new_suffix[0] == '.':
        new_suffix += '.'
    return string[:i] + new_suffix
```

Answer (score 0):

`glob.iglob()` yields pathnames, without the character '*'. 
therefore your line should be:

```
new_file_name = item.replace('.rtf', '.txt')
```

consider working with clearer names (reserve 'filename' for a file name and use 'path' for a complete path to a file; use 'path_original' instead of 'item'), os.extsep ('.' in Windows) and os.path.splitext():

```
path_txt = os.extsep.join([os.path.splitext(path_original)[0], 'txt'])
```

now the best hint of all:
numpy can probably [read your file directly](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/InputOutput#head-77923dc80cfe0961d74adaca2eaa5fb3de02126f):

```
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, unpack=True)
```

(see also [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html))

To better understand where your `TypeError` comes from, wrap your code in the following try/except block:

```
try:
    (your code)
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Minor correction to your comment:  `os.sep` is \\ in Windows, not `.`

Comment: From the glob docs (http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.glob) "pathname can be either absolute (like /usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile) or relative (like ../../Tools/*/*.gif), and can contain shell-style wildcards". If I understand this correctly, the pathname could include the "*" character, but isn't guaranteed to.

Comment: True: it <b>excepts</b> wildcards etc. But it <b>returns</b> complete path names, so in the 'item', there is no more wildcard.